# JavaScript Alert won't trigger

Tags: javascript

**JS**

```
    var health = document.getElementById("health")

    $(document).ready(function(){ 
        $('.heal').click(function(){
                var healthval = +document.getElementById('health').getAttribute('value')
                console.log(healthval)
                if (healthval === 1) {
                    alert("It's already full!");
                } else {
                    document.getElementById('health').setAttribute('value', healthval + 0.1);
                    alert("You give your critter some food!");
                }      
                if (healthval > 1) {
                    healthval = 1;
                }
                if (healthval === 0) {
                    alert("Your critter has died! Oh no!");
                }
            });
    });
```

**HTML**

```
<meter low=".5" optimum=".8" high=".7" id="health" value="0.1"></meter>
<button type="button" class="heal">Heal Me</button>
```

I'm using the above code for a 'health bar' in a little project I'm working on.
I'm pretty happy with it as the health does up / down as it's supposed to. Only thing is, for some reason, the `alert("It's already full!");` and `alert("Your critter has died! Oh no!");` parts aren't happening when they should be....but the `alert("You give your critter some food!");` triggers every time.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Because it's always going to end up in else part!

Comment: have you had a look at your console? `healthval` actually never becomes 1 or 0...

Comment: I've been writing this project live on [link](http://www.codecademy.com/) and have no idea how to view the console on that. How would I amend it so that the healthval DOES change?

Comment: As you dont have dynamic values, agree with @DhavalMarthak

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combine statement `if (healthval === 1)` & `if (healthval > 1)` and better use `if else block` rather than only `if blocks` when you are checking conditions on same variable.

Try this-

```js
var health = document.getElementById("health")

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.heal').click(function () {
        var healthval = document.getElementById('health').getAttribute('value') * 1;
        if (healthval >= 1) {
            alert("It's already full!");
        } else if (healthval === 0) {
            alert("Your critter has died! Oh no!");
        } else {            
            document.getElementById('health').setAttribute('value', healthval + 0.1);
            console.log(healthval)
            alert("You give your critter some food!");
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<meter low=".5" optimum=".8" high=".7" id="health" value="0.1"></meter>
<button type="button" class="heal">Heal Me</button>
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked beautifully and is nice and compact

Answer (score 1):

Although an answer is already accepted, I had some fun trying to find a solution, so I just recreated the whole thing, simplified it, created a function for the feedback (got rid of `alert`), and added a 'Kill Me' button. :)

Here is what I came up with (thanks to @vikrant singh for the 'code snippet' markup):

```js
healthval = $("#health").val();
function feedback(healthval) {    
    if (healthval >= 1) {
        $('#msg').text("It's already full!");
    } else if (healthval === 0) {
        $('#msg').text("Your critter has died! Oh no!");
    } else {
        $('#msg').text("You give your critter some food!");
    }
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.heal').click(function () {
        healthval = $("#health").val();
        $("#health").val(healthval + 0.1);
        console.log(healthval);
        feedback(healthval);
    });
    $('.kill').click(function () {
        healthval = $("#health").val();
        $("#health").val(healthval - 0.1);
        console.log(healthval);
        feedback(healthval);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<meter low=".5" optimum=".8" high=".7" id="health" value="0.1"></meter>
<button type="button" class="heal">Heal Me</button>
<button type="button" class="kill">Kill Me</button>
<div id="msg"></div>
```

Here is the fiddle link so you can edit it for your own enjoyment: http://jsfiddle.net/uruws5ov/1/

Comment: hehe, happy you like it ;)